# React context reset consumer state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

I m trying to use React Context API to pass state data from a Parent component to a deep nested Child.

The parent is a class component and the child is a function.

When from the child i update the parent state with a function passed through the Context the parent state is updated successfully but then the local state of the child is reset to the initial value.

Parent:

```
 export class ObjectLinking extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                setCurrentlyDisplayed: this.setCurrentlyDisplayed,
                currentlyDisplayed: []
            };
        }

        [...]

        render() {
            return (
                <ObjectLinkingContext.Provider value={this.state}>
{//Panel body will contain deep nested child that is connected to context}
                   <PanelBody />
                </ObjectLinkingContext.Provider>
            );
        }
    }
```

Child:

```
  import ObjectLinkingContext from '../../context/ObjectLinkingContext';
    const AssetListFilters = ({ assets, filtersModel }) => {
        const [searchByNameVal, setSearchByNameVal] = useState([]);
        const panelContext = useContext(ObjectLinkingContext);

        useEffect(() => {
            filterBySearchNameVal();
        }, [searchByNameVal]);

        const filterBySearchNameVal = () => {
            if (searchByNameVal.length) {
                const { setCurrentlyDisplayed } = panelContext;
                const { value: searchedId } = searchByNameVal[0];
                const searchedAsset = assets.filter(asset => asset.assetId === searchedId) || [];
                setCurrentlyDisplayed(searchedAsset);
            }
        };

        return (
                        <Autocomplete
                            onChange={val => setSearchByNameVal(val)}
                        />

      );
    };
```

Find [here](https://bitbucket.org/snippets/salvatore-me/ynzaMe) the full Parent.js and VeryDeepChild.js component

Comment: Could you please post the relevant code?

Comment: Note that **relevant** is the thing to focus on. Posting a link to almost 300 lines of code and basically asking "What wrong?" isn't how you should post a question.

Comment: You have a `useEffect` in the child that means you are calling `setCurrentlyDisplayed(searchedAsset)` on initial render. Whenever context state is updated, all children that use that context get re-rendered. Is this your intention?

Comment: @JMadelaine At the initial render `searchByNameVal.length` is  `0` so `setCurrentlyDisplayed ` won't be called.
I am using the useEffect as i want to call that `setCurrentlyDisplayed` when `searchByNameVal` is updated

Comment: If you want the parent state to match the child state, why have any child state at all? just keep track of that state in the parent

Comment: Ahh yes you're right Salvatore. I missed the length check.

Comment: @azium i don't want the parent state to match the child state. I just want the child to have control of a portion of the parent state.

Comment: what's different about the child state and the parent state? whether its a portion or not, is it not duplicated?

Comment: anyways, it's not clear from the code you posted why the state is resetting. maybe it's just the autocomplete returns an empty array when you close it?